# AddClass to match statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to allocate `tbody` into 1 of 2 different class. I can't seem to get the if statement running, perhaps I have not used the syntax correctly?


condition 1: If tbody id = today (yyyymm), then add class "current"

condition 2: If tbody id < today (yyyymm), then add class "past"

condition 3: If tbody id > today (yyyymm), then add do nothing

```js
$(function(){
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var output = d.getFullYear() + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month;
var checktbody = $('tbody').attr('id');
//alert(output);

if(checktbody == output) {
$(this).addclass("current");
}

//$("table#ttrate").find("tbody".attr("id") == output).addclass("current");

});
```

```css
table#ttx{margin-left:40px; border-collapse:collapse;}
#ttx th {padding-top: 18px; text-align:left;}
#ttx td {padding-left: 18px;}
#ttx tbody.current {background-color: #FFFF99;}
#ttx tbody.past {color: #B8B8B8;}
```

```html
<table id="ttx">
<tbody id="201801">
<tr><th colspan="2">Jan-2018</th></tr>
<tr><td>Buy</td><td>23,000</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sell</td><td>10,250</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody id="201712">
<tr><th colspan="2">Dec-2017</th></tr>
<tr><td>Buy</td><td>20,000</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sell</td><td>12,500</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody id="201711">
<tr><th colspan="2">Nov-2017</th></tr>
<tr><td>Buy</td><td>10,000</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sell</td><td>8,750</td></tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: If I do remember, that should be `.addClass()` method.

Comment: You need to loop over all the tbody elements, reading the id only selects the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to check whether **each** `tbody` has matching `id`.

Your original syntax `var checktbody = $('tbody').attr('id');` only gets  **one** `tbody` from all the tbodies.

So, what you need to do is to use `for loop` in pure JavaScript, or if in jQuery, a [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```
$('tbody').each(function(index, tb){

    // Do all your if-else logic here
    if (tb.id == output)
        $(tb).addClass(...);

    /* more logic here */

});
```

```js
$(function(){
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var output = d.getFullYear() + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month;

/* DELETE THIS
var checktbody = $('tbody').attr('id');
//alert(output);

if(checktbody == output) {
$(this).addclass("current");
}
*/

// ADD THIS
$('tbody').each(function(i, v){

  if (v.id == output)
    $(this).addClass('current');

  /* more logic here */

});

//$("table#ttrate").find("tbody".attr("id") == output).addclass("current");

});
```

```css
table#ttx{margin-left:40px; border-collapse:collapse;}
#ttx th {padding-top: 18px; text-align:left;}
#ttx td {padding-left: 18px;}
#ttx tbody.current {background-color: #FFFF99;}
#ttx tbody.past {color: #B8B8B8;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ttx">
<tbody id="201801">
<tr><th colspan="2">Jan-2018</th></tr>
<tr><td>Buy</td><td>23,000</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sell</td><td>10,250</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody id="201712">
<tr><th colspan="2">Dec-2017</th></tr>
<tr><td>Buy</td><td>20,000</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sell</td><td>12,500</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody id="201711">
<tr><th colspan="2">Nov-2017</th></tr>
<tr><td>Buy</td><td>10,000</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sell</td><td>8,750</td></tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Yong. I appreciate how you explain what my syntax was and wasn't doing too. Big THANKS!!

Comment: @Maki glad it helped ;). However, I noticed a typo in your original code where `.addClass()` is incorrectly typed as `.addclass()`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, grab each `tbody` on the page and loop through each one using `$.each`:

```
$.each( $("tbody"), function(index, el) { ... });
```

In order to achieve the 3 conditions that you stated, we have to rethink how the application is currently coded. Right now, you are comparing strings to see whether the element's date is current or past.

A better way of doing this would be to use `Date` objects to facilitate date comparisons.

See the code below. We use regular expressions to extract year and month from the `id` of each `tbody` and we use that to create a `Date` object, which we then compare to today's `Date` object:

```js
$(function(){

  var now = new Date(); // today's date
  var nowYear = now.getFullYear();
  var nowMonth = now.getMonth();

  var today = new Date(nowYear, nowMonth);
  var todayTime = today.getTime(); // get today in milliseconds so we can run comparisons

  $.each( $("tbody"), function(index, el) {

    var $el = $(el);
    var id = $el.attr('id');

    // Get year, month, day using regex
    var rxArr = id.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})/); 
    var year = rxArr[1];
    var month = parseInt(rxArr[2]) - 1; // we need month - 1 to pass to Date object

    var elDate = new Date(year, month);
    var elDateTime = elDate.getTime(); // returns milliseconds so we run comparisons

    if(elDateTime === todayTime) {
      $el.addClass("current");
    } else if(elDateTime < todayTime) {
      $el.addClass("past");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
table#ttx{margin-left:40px; border-collapse:collapse;}
#ttx th {padding-top: 18px; text-align:left;}
#ttx td {padding-left: 18px;}
#ttx tbody.current {background-color: #FFFF99;}
#ttx tbody.past {color: #B8B8B8;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<table id="ttx">
  <tbody id="201801">
  <tr><th colspan="2">Jan-2018</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Buy</td><td>23,000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sell</td><td>10,250</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody id="201712">
  <tr><th colspan="2">Dec-2017</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Buy</td><td>20,000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sell</td><td>12,500</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody id="201711">
  <tr><th colspan="2">Nov-2017</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Buy</td><td>10,000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Sell</td><td>8,750</td></tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```